# How to compute this sum in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, sum

How to compute this sum in Matlab in a compact manner? (n is a value related to each s)

[image]

I have done:

```
  NUM = 0;
  DEN = 0;
  max_s = max(s);

  for f = 1 : length(s)
     n = sum(s == s(f));
     if (s(f) ~= max_s)
         NUM = NUM + s(f) * s(f) * n;
     end
     DEN = DEN + s(f) * n;
  end

  result = NUM / DEN;
```

Comment: Sorry I just made an error while retyping code, I edited. That scalar type is n.

Comment: are you sure about `n`? if you have in `s` an element that appears twice, you'll sum it twice **each time** multiplying it by 2...

Comment: n is defined as the number of s(i) in s... (i as iteration index)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

assuming `s` is a vecotr and `n` is a vector of the same length as `s`, then the sum

```
sel = s < max(s(:)); % select relevant entries 
sum( n( sel ) .* s(sel).^2 ) ./ sum( s.*n )
```

in your example `n=sum( bsxfun( @eq, s, s' ), 1 )`.

Note that you can use dot product to cumpute `sum( x .* y ) = x(:)' * y(:)`.
However, when you use this trick you need to be careful with the dimensionality of the vectors, otherwise you'll find yourself computing outer-product....

Comment: Sorry, I edited another time: n is a scalar and it is the count of s(f) inside s

Comment: @misiMe I also edited my answer to reflect this change. `n` is NOT a scalar, but a vector of the same length as `s`, you use different `n` for each `s(f)`.

Comment: @Shai What is `num`? You probably mean `n`

Comment: @Shai Oh now I see my answer is the same as this. Deleting it

Answer (score 0):

For the specific definition of `n`, you can use `hist` and `unique`

```
us = unique( s );
n = hist( s, us ); %// count 
sel = us < max(us);
row = @(x) x(:).'; %//' convert to row vector
col = @(x) x(:); %// convert to col vector
result = ( row( us(sel).^2 ) * col( n(sel).^2 ) ) / ( row( us ) * col( n.^2 ) )
```

comparison of my two answers canbe found at [ideone](https://ideone.com/Kx0L9r).

Comment: Are your two answers equivalent?

Comment: @misiMe they are, see my ideone comparison.